# Laravel error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Model' not found

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having troubles using eloquent with Laravel.
I am getting an error which I found a lot here on SO but didn't find a solution to it.

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Activity' not found
```

After searching in the asked questions, it appears everyone omitted the use App/'Model' statement, but I included it in my controller, still getting this error, and I don't know what I am doing wrong

My model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Activity extends Model
{
    public function covers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cover');
    }

    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Activity;

class ActivityController extends Controller
{
    public function get_wixer_activities($wid){
        $activities = App\Activity::all();
        dd($activities);
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: If you have `use App\Activity` you just need `Activity::all`.

Comment: what is location of model. I think you need to put the model in "App" Folder dirtectly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are importing the `Activity` class here:

```
use App\Activity;
```

It means you can use the `Activity` class like this:

```
$activities = Activity::all();
```

And you don't need the `App\Activity`.

Comment: Yep, and if you didn't have the `use` statement, you'd need `$activities = \App\Activity::all();` with the leading \.